# multiplying for loop in a browser history system

Tags: java, csv, for-loop, methods

I guess, I've been writing a web browser for a project and I am finding that I am unable to make my history system work as intended,at this current moment I am finding that my history items are replicating, my history duplicates itself between sessions based on a for-loop style pyramid where the size of the pyramid is n-1 of how many pages i visited last session:

pages duplicated | pages visited last session

```
    1                        1
    12                       2
    123                      3
    1234                     4
```

This method is called whenever I travel to a new page and the if statement in the top half is only run once, when the browser is launched and is there to recover previous session's histories from the CSV file it is stored in.

The code is supposed to create a jmenuitem every time a page is traveled to, and then add that to the jmenu, this is done fine, however, it is also supposed to add the link to a list. The list is then appended to the csv for storage.

```
public class FileBar extends JMenuBar {
    int tracker = 0;
    File histPath = new File("history.csv");
    JMenu history = new JMenu("History");
    List<String> histStore = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void createhistory(String webAddress) {
        try {
            List<String> histFeedback = new ArrayList<String>();
            writer = new FileWriter(histPath, true);
            if (tracker < 1) {
                  // system to retrieve information from csv file upon launch of program
            }       

            JMenuItem button = new JMenuItem(webAddress);
            history.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               // ...
            });

            histStore.add(webAddress);
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < histStore.size(); i++) {

                writer.append(histStore.get(i));
                writer.append(",");
            }

            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Would it be possible to test a bit more and see if you can narrow down where the problem is, then revise the question to only include that section (and describe the exact issue)?

Comment: @br1ckb0t I've taken out what I can, but I think we lose the essence of what the code is trying to do now... also the first paragraph says exactly what is wrong with my code, my history duplicates itself between sessions based on a for-loop style pyramid where the size of the pyramid is n-1 of how many pages i visited last session

Comment: Great, thanks. That helps a lot. The code makes sense now, but I'm not sure that the issue is here. So just to clarify - could you clarify in your opening paragraph where the problem is? Is it `f.histStore`, the `csv`, somewhere else?

Comment: @br1ckb0t i've updated the question and there's been some slight code changes that are detailed in another comment, however I still cannot get it to work, could you please advise?

Comment: Got it @BenBowen. Check my answer - is that what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's what (I think) is the issue. Each time you visit a page, you seem to be *appending* the *entire history* to the line in the CSV.

I don't know where `f.histStore` comes from, but I assume it's created from the line in the CSV. So if there are 5 addresses in the CSV, then it seems that `f.histStore.size() == 5`.

So when you go to a page, you append that address it to `f.histStore`:

```
f.histStore.add(webAddress);
```

Ok, looking good so far. But then, you *append* `f.histStore` to the line that was originally read from:

```
for (i = 0; i < f.histStore.size(); i++) {
    writer.append(f.histStore.get(i));
    writer.append(",");
}
```

So you've appended the entirety of the list to the existing list. So this would result in a duplicate pattern, like this, where `a`, `b`, and `c` are addresses:

```
a
aab
aabaabc
```

If that's what's occurring, there's a simple solution: only write the last address to the file. Replace the write loop with:

```
int lastIndex = f.histStore.size() - 1;
writer.append(f.histStore.get(lastIndex));
writer.append(",");
```

Does that do it? If not, what is the incorrect output?

Comment: I had to make some edits to another section of code, also the f. was irrelevant as it referred to the class itself and was a leftover piece of code I forgot to clean up when posting the question to stack, but because you've been willing and helpful and because you led me to my answer, have my thanks and the answer mark

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Glad you could get it figured out - especially since figuring it out on your own is the best way to learn anyways :).

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be happening, assuming that pyramid problem is happening in your csv, is that your are writing your history list to the csv every time you visit a page.  First page you visit will append the page to the list, and then write it to the csv.  Second page you visit will append the page to the list, and then write the full list to the csv because of this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < f.histStore.size(); i++) {

    writer.append(f.histStore.get(i));
    writer.append(",");
}
```

You either need to overwrite the line in the csv, or just append your most recent item.

Comment: I changed that section of code to: `int i = 0;
      
       writer.append(histStore.get(i));
       writer.append(",");
      i++;
 ` however now the method does not write at all